# UITableViewCell change Image without calling Reload (LazyLoading)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, lazy-loading

I have looked at some sample LazyLoading to load the image whenever the cells are visible and the loading is complete. I noticed they do not call ReloadData How do I change the images without having to call ReloadData or reloading a specific row?

I figured that changing the image data at the address would do it, but it doesn't work.

I tried

```
 for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
{

        UIBubbleTableViewCell *aCell = (UIBubbleTableViewCell *)[self.bubbleTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSBubbleData *cellData = [aCell data];
        cellData.avatar = [self.profileImages objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cellData posterID]]];

}
```

However, this does not update the image. I have to call ReloadData after the for loop for it to load the image. If I do not call ReloadData it will not update until the cell goes off the screen again and comes back into view.

Comment: If using third party frameworks works for you, try using SDWebImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `UIBubbleTableViewCell`, it does not appear to handle updates to the data. However, it looks like the the data is re-applied anytime you set the cell's frame. So doing something like this might be a workaround (I don't use this library so I can't test it):

```
aCell.frame = aCell.frame;
```

Comment: wow you are correct. I added that line of code and it did work without reloading data. Could you share how you determined whether when data is re-applied or when it isn't? I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you look at the source code for `UIBubbleTableViewCell`, you can see that there is a `setFrame` method override that calls `setupInternalData`, which is the method that applies the data.